# Globe not freezing the water (Act 3 full game)

Tags: hello-neighbor

In Hello Neighbor act 3, you need to grab the globe, freeze it in your freezer, and then put it in the little spherical holder. After that, it says that you can go up to the water that is blocking off the red gramophone, and it should be frozen. This is not the case for me, as although the globe is frozen solid, the water is still very much a liquid. Does anyone know either what I am doing wrong, or what I need to fix? I am playing on PS4 on the latest version.

(I have already tried waiting for it while it was in the freezer for at least 15 minutes, and I have already tried restarting my console and my game as well.)